# Lots of "Failed to get renderer info [0x5 (os/kern) failure]" coming in console when I debug views

Tags: swift, macos-ventura

I'm creating a pet project and there's one strange issue. When I open Debug View Hierarchy, a lot of similar errors appear in console. It looks like:

```
2023-06-14 15:47:07.356740+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.356807+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.359829+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.359904+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.359964+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.363650+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
2023-06-14 15:47:07.363726+0300 BFB[19678:4582894] [API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x42b6b2ed) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]
```

(And so many of them)

What are they caused by and how can I remove this? My pet project is just simple, only standard UIKit items like UIViews / UITableViews are used.

I'm using Apple M2 Max CPU with 32 Gb RAM and Mac OS Ventura 13.4

Swift version is 5.8.1 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.5 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)

It may be related to project, because I created another from scratch, placed simple label and tried to debug its views - errors didn't appear.

Thank you.

Comment: Restarting Xcode / cleaning Build folder / restarting my Mac, unfortunately, doesn't help.

Comment: I get these errors when loading View Hierarchy of an Objective-C project when testing with a simulator running iOS 16.2, but not for iOS 15.5.  Its probably just one of the bugs in iOS 16.x, or in how Xcode handles iOS 16.x.  As long as your app is working correctly and the View Hierarchy is showing you the data you need to see, you can probably just ignore these errors.

Comment: Thank you, jk7. My iOS target is 16.0, but, unfortunately I can't set it to 15.5 right now cause I'm using new regex so I have to refactor a lot of code to try testing it.

Comment: I asked the same question on Apple Development Forum, hoping that I'll get the answer but, unfortunately, nobody replied yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because my MacBook has been repaired for a long time, I continued working on my pet project using MacOs Sonoma (14.0).

Project has not been changed since I posted my question, but these errors have completely gone.

So I guess it was Ventura bug, as jk7 said.

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue.
Please try to use Debug Navigator -> View UI Hierarchy Tool to view all views at the moment showing logs.
You maybe see another view being overlapping 0x42b6b2ed view, so it failed to render.

In my case, I tried to dismiss all views before showing a new one.